How to export tdata of telegram to session of WTelegramClient
I want to transfer session from telegram desktop or mobile in folder tdata to telegram session of WTelegramClient how can i do this.
Thanks
I tried to find a way to use opentele to move the tdata folder to the telethon session, then from the telethon session to the WTelegramClient session but it didn't work.

What you're asking is specifically against Telegram API Terms of Service: https://core.telegram.org/api/terms

2.1. You must obtain your own api_id for your application.

Just create another session with WTelegramClient (using your own api_id/hash obtained here), providing the verification_code that will be transmitted to the existing Telegram app session.
(it is perfectly fine to have multiple sessions for the same phone number)
But we know perfectly well that people trying to extract (or rather buy) sessions from tdata/official apps are doing this to mass-manage lots of sessions for nefarious intents. So you're not going to get help.
